# mkdir: Permission denied inside docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am relatively new on linux so having some permission issues. Basically i am trying to run an iota wasp node with docker compose, but it gives me an error:

**could not create directory:mkdir /waspdb/CHAIN_REGISTRY permission denied**

[image]

**What I tried:**

- I have tried to run docker-compose command as **root**
- Tried to change permission with **chmod 0777** but the issue persists.

**How to regenerate issue:**

- Clone repo: (**git clone https://github.com/iotaledger/wasp.git**)
- Checkout to master branch
- cd wasp/tools/devnet
- docker-compose up

You can also find **dockerfile** and **docker_config** file in repo. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve] in the question itself, not behind a link.  Also make sure you've included the error message as plain text and not an image.

Comment: I guess you need to create the volume waspdb as is in the docker-compose file

Comment: Maybe you can explain it a bit more as i dont know how to do that. Thanks